# Auto Round Off in Python3

Tags: python

I wrote a code for finding the 'j' for the General Annuity

```
from __future__ import division

R = float(38973.76)
n = int(3)
r = int(8)
m = int(4)
mSubj = int(1)
t = int(3)
ans = ((1 + r / m) ** m)**(1 / mSubj) - 1

print(ans)
```

now the answer is `80.0`
instead of `0.008243216` that I solved in Scientific Calculator.

Comment: Can you explain on how you are expecting `0.008243216`? What formula are you trying to emulate?

Comment: You don't need to specify types with `int()` and `float()`. `38973.76` is the literal notation for a `float`, `3` is the literal notation for an `int`.

Comment: 0.008243216 is the answer in Scientific Calculator with the same calculations of formula

Comment: Can you post the math formula? Python is indeed correct.

Comment: @L3viathan Line 1 doesn't give `0.008243216` either.

Comment: @L3viathan Oops. Unrelated: that line isn't necessary if the OP really is using Python 3.

Comment: https://imgur.com/3FDDz5c

Comment: wait the frick up I forgot to convert the r (rate) into decimal. Its ok now! Thanks to all of you`

Answer (score 1):

Your `R` variable is the capital one, not `r`.

so it should be `ans = ((1 + R / m) ** m)**(1 / mSubj) - 1`

Comment: This also doesn't give the expected result though.

Comment: nah mate, r and R is different.

Comment: I just forgot to convert the r (rate) into decimal

Comment: so you declared `R` for what?

Comment: for the next formula! HAHAHA